# Any trigger after OnBeforeUnload?

Tags: javascript, triggers

I'd like to execute some javascript after a form/file was send, but before the next page loads. Normally, I would execute the script on the landing page, but it is a 3rd party API. The `onbeforeunload` does actually fire as soon as the form is submitted, but it takes minutes for it to send (file upload).

Is here any trigger I could use instead of this one? Thanks

Comment: Have tried the `unload` event? (`onunload`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I've created an iframe and handeled it's `onload` event. Messy solution as it's worse, but that goes with using 3rd party pages I presume.

Answer (score 0):

There's `onunload`, but I'm not sure when it fires in this case (definitely after `onbeforeunload` :))

Note that AJAX in `onunload` is very finicky and may never execute.

Comment: Yep, it does never fire. Gonna try some tricks with location changes if there are any.